# PostgreSQL: Search all tables of a database for a field called LIKE *active*

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, pgadmin

In my public schema I have 1200 tables.
Somewhere in one or more of this tables there are some fields called LIKE "*active*"
like:
- status_active
- hr_active
- who_knows_what_active_could_be

I want to find them all using PGAdmin in the console or via the normal client on console
how could I do this with quick with less resources?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE TRUE
AND table_schema = 'public'
AND column_name ~* 'active'
```

Comment: @eichertc This query list all tables and `views` of only schema `public`, and this not what you were looking for.

Comment: it's just posix regexp match operator. read more: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Comment: I been searching for this table "information_schema.columns", where is it ?

Comment: In your database server :) :
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/infoschema-schema.html

Comment: and in pgAdmin: <<server>> -> <<database>> -> catalogs -> ANSI (information_schema)

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
SELECT table_name,tables.table_catalog,tables.table_schema,column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
inner join information_schema.tables
using(table_name,table_schema)
WHERE  table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  and column_name ilike '%active%'
```

Comment: if you want to be THAT precise, you should add a condition: using(table_name, table_schema)... Without it you'll get duplicate entries in case the same table name exists in more than one schema

Comment: I found out that most of the tables are in fact empty. so I try to find out where in the information_schema there is a info about nr of rows in the tables.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your schema name'
--and TABLE_NAME ilike '%your keyword%' --when you need to search for a TABLE
and COLUMN_NAME ilike '%your keyword%' --when you need to search for a COLUMN
```